# Captcha refresh button is not showing in Captcha MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The captcha refresh button is not showing and I would like to add an image instead of a button.

```
string captchaenable = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CaptchaEnabled"];

if (captchaenable == "True")
{
    @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "<b>Captcha Code:</b>", 5, "Is required field", false)<p>@ViewBag.ErrMessage</p>
}
```

[image: example]